# Video Library for Processing 4 does not run on this architecture: macos-aarch64 - Mac M1

Tags: processing, apple-m1

`import processing.video.*;`

error -
Video Library for Processing 4 does not run on this architecture: macos-aarch64

Processing 4.0b8 installed (Apple Silicon)
Video Library for Processing 4 2.1 installed
Mac M1 CPU

Comment: Looks like its not supported (yet) - https://github.com/processing/processing-video/issues/194#issuecomment-1027911051

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed with the latest release `2.2.1` -
https://github.com/processing/processing-video/releases/tag/latest

More info here -
https://github.com/processing/processing-video/issues/199